# Why doesn't adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth work

Tags: ios, swift

I create a UILabel like this, but nothing happens, the text does not increase.

my code:

```
    firstLabel = UILabel()
    firstLabel.text = "Выберите 2 лица"
    firstLabel.textColor = UIColor(alpha: 1, red: 64, green: 156, blue: 255)
    firstLabel.textAlignment = .center
    firstLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    firstLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

    firstLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(firstLabel)
    firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 3 * widthView/8).isActive = true
    firstLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    firstLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeWidthView - 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: Can you show what your code outputs, and what you expect it to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will not increase the font size to fill the remaining space in label if the label  has bigger width than the actual content size, it is intended to only shrink the font size to appropriate value to accommodate text if text is bigger than than label's bounding rectangle

Quoting apple

> Normally, the label draws the text with the font you specify in the
> font property. If this property is true, and the text in the text
> property exceeds the label’s bounding rectangle, the label reduces the
> font size until the text fits or it has scaled the font down to the
> minimum font size. The default value for this property is false. If
> you change it to true, be sure that you also set an appropriate
> minimum font scale by modifying the minimumScaleFactor property. This
> autoshrinking behavior is only intended for use with a single-line
> label.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Comment: @РустемСайфуллин : You're welcome :)  am glad I could help :) you can accept the answer if it really helped you by clicking on tick mark next to my answer :)